# Serve images with Django

Tags: python, django

I am sending my images from my web server Django like follows :

```
localhost:8000/media/images/foo.png
```

My question is am I sending the images is the correct way? I think it is not necessary to send the server since I am the only one who serves the photographs. Any ideas, something like this `media/images/foo.png`.
In order that in the `img` tag of HTML this is a relative path and not a link.

Answer (score 4):

For serving images in Django,

First make sure that you have your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` defined inside the settings.py file.

Now let's say you have a model, models.py

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'your_directory_inside_media')
    #Rest of the fields
```

Next inside your views,

```
model_object = SomeModel.objects.get(...) #get an instance of model which has an ImageField
context = {'image' : model_object.image }
html = render(request , 'some_html.html' , context)
```

And finally inside your HTML,

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ image.image }}">
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: But, I don't use views from django, I create an angular app and send that url to access to image

Comment: You can get the url by using "image.name" . It'll give you the complete URL.

Comment: but, why I need add `{% load static %}` If my data is save in `media`??

Comment: It wouldn't work without it. It even uses it in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix  .

Comment: You pointed out something interesting. Indeed, even I never though about it. But the original post didn't asked about this, otherwise this is something even I don't know anything about. I couldn't find an answer for this question anywhere, so I posted a question here myself.

Comment: @fm433403  found an answer to your question. I asked it and got a convincing answer. It's just a convention to use it all in the static files because, when the static.py module was created, its use case was targeting a set of files(Media and Static) that came under the same umbrella. Read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656855/why-is-load-static-a-dependency-for-get-media-prefix

Answer (score 0):

Just some feedback after I struggled with a similar issue for hours. I overlooked a part of the documentation where to actually use`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` you must add
`'django.template.context_processors.media'` to the 'context_processors' list in settings.py