# Why is {% load static %} a dependency for {% get_media_prefix %}?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media

I've been using `{% get_media_prefix %}` for a very long time. I was explaining this to someone when he pointed this out.

**Why do I need to declare `{% load static %}` in order to use it?**

It even uses in the documentation's example code [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix).

To an extent I understand that static files and media files are similar in nature. Even when we use them with combination of nginx+gunicorn, nginx handles both of them(we let everything else proxy, but not these).

**But** still we have a separate `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` as well as `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` defined for these files.

Then why `{% load static %}` needs to be declared in order to use `{% get_media_prefix %}` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a template tag in your HTML you must first [load](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-load) the module that contains it.

So, accorrding to the [source code of `get_media_prefix` template tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4696078832f486ba63f0783a0795294b3d80d862/django/templatetags/static.py#L76), this template tag lives inside `django/templatetags/static.py`.

That's why you have to `load` it every time you use it, in every HTML template.

This, of course, applies to every template tag usage. At the top of every HTML file you load the template tags and then you use them. Just like you `import` a function in your python code.

UPDATE: From the [Django 1.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.3/#extended-static-files-handling):

> In previous versions of Django, it was common to place static assets in `MEDIA_ROOT` along with user-uploaded files, and serve them both at `MEDIA_URL`. Part of the purpose of introducing the staticfiles app is to make it easier to keep static files separate from user-uploaded files. Static assets should now go in `static/` subdirectories of your apps or in other static assets directories listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, and will be served at `STATIC_URL`.

As you can see, Django used to treat both static and media the same. Since Django 1.3 this changed, but the template tag not. No big deal. It's just a convention.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. I understand that because it's kept in that module, that's why I need to load it. It's a dependency. But is there a specific reason because of which a tag containing the "media prefix" kept in "django/templatetags/static.py"? Clearly django differentiates between media files and static files. Then why is something related to media files kept in the static.py module?

Comment: Also I understand that maybe it is done to bring more uniformity or something. But I was just wondering that if there was a specific reason to do so. To keep it in a module which doesn't describe it the best.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. The straight answer to your question is *I don't know*. It's actually an implementation/decision reason.
 
Yes, Django does differentiates between static and media files, but paying a closer look at the docs ([`Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS`)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)), Django includes both of them in the same doc file.

You can always, contribute (by opening a ticket) to propose this template tag to live under `django/templatetags/media.py` and then you must type `{% load media %}`.

Comment: Exactly. Although the type of files that live in the "media" or "static" are similar in a broad way, but django at the end of the day does differentiates between the two. This makes the existence slightly peculiar. Perhaps the authors thought of something. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer to point you to the introduction of the `staticfiles` app. However, since what you're asking in your original question has been answered, mark the answer as correct or let it flow in the void... :)

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. Static settings came after Media settings in our settings.py. Yes, this is something convincing. This somewhat makes sense. Thanks a lot for finding this addition for me. I tried searching my problem, but couldn't find anything related to this. Thanks again.

Comment: I’m having an issue where I need to use staticfiles, but I cannot use the get_media_prefix when I {% load static from staticfiles %}

Comment: @Deven. You should ask a separate question with your issue. I would be glad to answer your question.